# Background view for text on image

Tags: ios, quartz-core

Attached is a screenshot for one of the promotional iPhone shots for Apple Music. Consider the first image for example. (Note, this isn't the first time Apple is using this kind of textual projection on an image).

[image]

I wish to use the same concept of layering text on the image as shown in the image, i.e. an auxiliary view layered over an image on which labels are added. I can use ColorArt (https://github.com/panicinc/ColorArt) to ascertain background color, primary and other supplementary colors. The background color can be used as the background color for the view on which the text is rendered. The other colors can be used as foreground colors for text.

The only part that I don't grasp here is the transparency effect that is attributed on the background view. Is it some kind of a partial blur or some kind of a gradient made of colors with variant alpha values? Can somebody explain how to create the background view in this case?